# What's 'all' referring to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Harry had deliberately left the trial of the Keepers until last, hoping for an emptier stadium and less pressure on **all** concerned. However, all the rejected players and a number of people who had come down to watch after a lengthy breakfast had joined the crowd by now, so that it was larger than ever.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince</sub>

I think 'all' here refers to those candidates who attended the tryout for the Keeper, but I have no confidence about it. How should we understand the phrase "less pressure on **all** concerned"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* is used as a pronoun here and it refers to *people*.

**All concerned** basically means, as you've concluded correctly, *all the people/candidates/spectators who were concerned/involved [with/in the trials]*.

Answer (score 1):

> *Harry had deliberately left the trial of the Keepers until last*,
>   *hoping for an emptier stadium and less pressure on **all concerned***.

"All" belongs to the category (part of speech) determinative.

Here it is in a special 'fused-head' NP, with a human interpretation, "all people".

It is more formal and less common that "everyone".

Answer (score 1):

"All concerned" is a very common phrase, almost an idiom, meaning "all those people who are interested in or involved with" whatever the subject is. This is related to the idiom "To whom it may concern" used to indicate that a letter or other communication is public, for anyone interested to read.

> The solution must satisfy all concerned.

means that the solution must be acceptable to everyone involved.